# Click HTML item passed through jQuery .each method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop in jQuery (the .each method) which loops through images in my DOM. I wish to programatically click one of these like so:

```
$("#gallery img").each(function(a, b){

    if(a === 10 ){    
        console.log(b); // outputs <img scr="path/image.gif alt data-id="Christmas0110">
        this.click();
    }

});
```

this does't seem to work, also when I change `this.click()` to `$(this).click()` I still get nothing! What am I doing wrong.

Comment: have you tried $(this).trigger('click')?

Comment: Override the click handler for the item you want to click first. Then you can just call the override function

Comment: $(this).click() should do it -- are you certain your event listener for the IMG tag is working? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: I tried $(this).click() and $(this).trigger('click') however both seem to fail in IE8

Comment: How is your click-event-listener attached, native js or jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simulate user clicking - you were close, but you need to pass `this` to jquery via: 
`$(this)`

```
$("#gallery img").each(function(a, b){

    if(a === 10 ){    
        console.log(b); // outputs <img scr="path/image.gif alt data-id="Christmas0110">
        $(this).click();
    }

});
```

I keep hearing that for some version of IE, you need to use `$(this).trigger("click")` - but I do not see any point in facilitating other's poor decisions (like using IE).

Furthermore, since you have the condition `a === 10` -- you probably want to take a different approach instead of iterating through all of them to get the one you want.

You could just do:

`$("#gallery img:nth-child(10)").click();`

(I think it should be 9, i forget how the indexes work)

Comment: I tried $(this).click() and $(this).trigger('click') however both seem to fail in IE8

Comment: for ie8 fail: how do you bind the click event to the img?

Comment: OK, ok - first, you have to use jQuery 1.11 --- then, if `.trigger("click")` still doesn't work, then try `.on("click", function() //[...]`

Answer (score 0):

The "this" in your function body refers to the img (DOM, not jQuery) at index 10. If you haven't bound any handler to it beforehand which actually does anything the behaviour (get nothing) is to be expected. A click on a plain img-tag should do nothing by default.

Comment: Woohoo, 5 answers during the time i was writing sth. Seems i'm way too slow for this :-)

Answer (score -4):

Firstly, you can't simulate an actual user click for obvious security reasons.

You can, however, act on the object passed as variable `b` in your `each` function.

eg: `doSomething(b);`

Comment: Actually, there are quite a few ways to dispatch click events which will simulate a user click.

Comment: Enacting events on an object in JavaScript, even if you bubble the event up the DOM is not the same thing as a user interaction which would, for example allow a new window to spawn despite a popup blocker being active, or allow a file to begin download with automatic download security settings being turned off.